# Chain dependant msi packages with burn

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

I have been struggling now for a few hours getting this working without any real success. I am trying to install ReportViewer 2012 (v11) including SQLSysClrTypes.msi with my installer.

My registry checks are as follow and seems to work:
`<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                         Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Redist\SQL Server System CLR Types\CurrentVersion"
                         Value="Version"
                         Variable="SQLSysClrTypesVerion" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                         Key="Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Redist\Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime"
                         Value="Version"
                         Variable="ReportViewer11Verion" />`

The package ref is as follow:
`<PackageGroup Id="ReportViewer11">
      <ExePackage Id="SQLSysClrTypes" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
                  SourceFile="reportviewer/SQLSysClrTypes.msi"
                  DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239643&quote;clcid=0x409"
                  DetectCondition="SQLSysClrTypesVerion" />
      <ExePackage Id="ReportViewer11" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
                  InstallCommand="/q"
                  SourceFile="reportviewer/ReportViewer.msi"
                  DownloadUrl="http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747"
                  DetectCondition="ReportViewer11Verion" />
    </PackageGroup>`

The log file for the installer states the following (not really helpful):

[0F08:10E0][2015-04-20T16:47:00]i304: Verified existing payload: ReportViewer11 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\54004C9B82D761A9AEB4EB73B85F5475D3771BAE\ReportViewer.msi.

[0F08:10E0][2015-04-20T16:47:00]i304: Verified existing payload: InstallationPackageId at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{A327D350-C9A6-4AA5-AA86-92E3B6653E77}v1.0.0.0\Avis.RAC.DARA.msi.

[0F08:04A4][2015-04-20T16:47:00]i301: Applying execute package: ReportViewer11, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\54004C9B82D761A9AEB4EB73B85F5475D3771BAE\ReportViewer.msi, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\54004C9B82D761A9AEB4EB73B85F5475D3771BAE\ReportViewer.msi" /q'

[0F08:04A4][2015-04-20T16:47:00]e000: Error 0x800700c1: Failed to CreateProcess on path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\54004C9B82D761A9AEB4EB73B85F5475D3771BAE\ReportViewer.msi

[0F08:04A4][2015-04-20T16:47:00]e000: Error 0x800700c1: Failed to execute EXE package.

[0E24:1164][2015-04-20T16:47:00]e000: Error 0x800700c1: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.

[0E24:1164][2015-04-20T16:47:00]i319: Applied execute package: ReportViewer11, result: 0x800700c1, restart: None

[0E24:1164][2015-04-20T16:47:00]e000: Error 0x800700c1: Failed to execute EXE package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using ExePackage for your msi files, use MsiPackage instead.